# Windows seems to insert additional bytes into python str

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, non-ascii-characters, python-unicode

I am trying to read a .json text file on Windows that includes various strings, one of which includes the "dot operator" unicode character U+22C5. It works just fine on my remote Ubuntu 18.04 machine. However, when I read the JSON file on a Windows machine, the unicode character gets mangled.

The JSON text file reads something like:

```
"Nm": {
    "Value": 1,
    "Symbol": "N⋅m"
}
```

However, after I have loaded the file using the python JSON module, it appears like this in my python dictionary (but only on Windows):

```
"Nm": {
    "Value": 1,
    "Symbol": "Nâ‹…m"
}
```

Note how the dot operator turned into something else.

I converted the two resulting strings into byte code to compare.

Byte code on Ubuntu:

```
>>> bytes("N⋅m", "utf-8")
>   b'N\xe2\x8b\x85m'
```

Byte code on Windows:

```
>>> bytes("N‹…m", "utf-8")
>   b'N\xc3\xa2\xe2\x80\xb9\xe2\x80\xa6m'
```

It seems that Windows is altering the byte code of the JSON file when it is being read in. I opened the JSON file in Notepad on Windows to see if the source file is interpreted differently on a Windows machine but is not: the dot operator appears correctly when viewed in Notepad.

Does anyone know why this is? Specifically, why when reading unicode characters on a linux machine generates different python byte code than when the same characters are read on a Windows machine?

Also, how can I prevent this from happening? Since this one character is a special case, I **could** fix it by using a `replace` method to swap out the characters but this seems hacky. I would like to just prevent this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I can fix the issue by using the `encoding='utf-8'` option when I open the file before I load it into the json loader. i.e.

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_unit_definitions:
    units_environment = json.load(json_unit_definitions)
```

Problem solved.

Comment: The docs for [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) state that the "default encoding is platform dependent (whatever `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns)". In Windows, the latter defaults to the system-locale encoding, "mbcs". In Windows 10, the system locale can be configured to use UTF-8.